# Is there a way to prove that the intersection of a decidable language and a recognizable language is also recognizable?

Tags: string, proof, turing-machines

I’m unsure if this is true or false, I’m thinking that all strings in a recognizable language are decidable, so the only strings in the intersection would be decidable? I’m not sure how to formalize this.

I tried doing the above by trying to prove that a recognizable language is also decidable.

Comment: https://youtu.be/sNWC1Zz6qcg?t=102 Yes, but there's a potential pitfall.